# Node js Engine not upgrading for firebase function node compatibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

**First failed**

Here is the *package.json*

```
 "engines": {
        "node": "8.0.0"
      },
```

> Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. Valid choices are: {"node": 10|12|14|16}
>
> Deploys to runtimes below Node.js 10 are now disabled in the Firebase CLI. Existing Node.js 8 functions will stop executing at a future date. Update existing functions to Node.js 10 or greater as soon as possible.

**I also try to upgrade the engine but getting this:**

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "10.0.0"
  },
```

then:

```
 npm install
```

then:

```
 firebase deploy --only functions
```

**Again getting this error:**

> Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. Valid choices are: {"node": 10|12|14|16}
>
> Deploys to runtimes below Node.js 10 are now disabled in the Firebase CLI. Existing Node.js 8 functions will stop executing at a future date. Update existing functions to Node.js 10 or greater as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that you need to provide either "10" or "12" or "14" or "16".  It should not contain dots.

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
```

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) as well.

Comment: okay, I did that but it's not deploying to the firebase functions still the errors.

Comment: Are you saying it's the same error, or something new? If you have a new error, please post it separately along with your debugging details.

Comment: no, it's just saying my deployment is complete but not deployed to my GCF, I've not seen it there.

Comment: does it because of the main running like we mostly have index.js? @doung-stevenson

Comment: I think you should post a new question and describe in detail what isn't working the way you expect, along with instructions that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.  You're probably doing something wrong, but we can't see what that is.

Comment: here it's: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72607649/14190819